# In socket programming,can I use read() system call in both server and client?

Tags: sockets

I wrote client server program using sockets, can I use read() system call in server program to read a message from client? When I use read() at server side, read is unsuccessful. It is returning -1.

Comment: Yes, and 6 more to go.

Comment: whne I use read system call at server side, read is unsuccessful. It is returnign -1

Comment: I have used read system call as read ( sockfd, recvBuff, sizeof( recvBuff )).

Comment: -1 indicates that there is an error occured. You should try to get more information about the reason of this error (connection closed, ...). And to get more help you should precise your question and include some code...

Comment: Since I'm assuming this is homework – new user asking about C smells like a systems programming assignment – I'm guessing you won't be able to use a third-party library in the code you hand in. However, for development you might find [`libexplain`](http://libexplain.sourceforge.net) handy – it's a library of wrappers around system calls that figures out the cause of their failure, and returns a helpful error message. You can always remove it later.

Comment: while sending a message from client program to server program I am getting error as "recv: Transport endpoint is not connected" what is the meaning of that error.And what actually causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `read()` on the server side.  A return value of -1 merely tells you that an error occurred, but not what the actual error is.  You need to look at `errno` (or equivalent) for that. Some errors, like `EWOULDBLOCK` and `EAGAIN`, are not fatal errors, but most others are.